# How to add reCAPTCHA v2 to an existing form using PHP?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I want to integrate a recaptcha to my functioning contact form using PHP. The PHP form is already set, so I figured I should go that route. I believe

I have all necessary variables and parameters are set, I just need to know where exactly to place the final recaptcha verification in my PHP form.

I've tried several iterations of the code, but it essentially short-circuits and ruins the function of the existing code.

HTML:

```html
<form action="php/contactform.php" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" id="contactForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITEKEYCODEALREADYHERE"></div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="submit">Send Message</button></div>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $subject = strip_tags(trim($_POST["subject"]));
                $subject = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$subject);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "me@cbonilla.dev";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "Subject: $subject";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        //reCAPTCHA Verification
        $secretKey = "SECRETCODEALREADYHERE";
        $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $UserIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretkey.'&response='.$responseKey.'&remoteip='.$UserIP.'";

        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($response);


        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been submitted, fam.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }
    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    } 

?>
```

I believe the final code snippet occurs after the "// Send the email." note. I've also already added the reCAPTCHA JS tag in the  section.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$data` so you never know if the captcha entry was valid or not.

Comment: @miken32 That's exactly what I need to know how to integrate. I think the necessary code is something like -- if ($data->success==true) -- but I don't know where to place it the code.

Comment: Before you send the email, of course.

Comment: `if ($data->success==true && mail(...))` for example.

Comment: @miken32 I added your code and plugged in my parameters in the same spot as above, no dice. Error is: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the check.  And this would go BEFORE the send message part.  Something like this:

```
if(!empty($data["success"])) {
   // You could put the actual sending of the mail in here.  Or, not.    
} else {
    echo "Your captcha failed!";
    exit();
}
```

The above would come right after your data = json_decode() line.

THAT answers your question.  But, consider this.  The doc for recaptcha (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) says that you must use a POST when calling the api endpoint to verify the captcha.  You can do this with a curl call, similar to the below:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'secret' => $secretKey,
        'response' => $captcha,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: When using your snippet, and placing the sending of the mail in 'there', I get a successful div message (I previously had a div message that said "Thank You!") that reads "Your captcha failed!" from the echo. No mail is sent.

Comment: Try using if (!$data->success) instead of if(!empty($data["success"])).  I dont have access to my php env at the moment, and am trying to do this from memory.

Comment: Alright, got something interesting. If I use your code R. Smith, which I take to mean "If data does not equal success", the email goes through without having to do the reCAPTCHA. If I use --- if ($data->success) --- without the exclamation, which I take to mean "If data equals success", the email does not go through even if I've filled the reCAPTCHA. So, it works but doesn't work correctly. Might be something else?